# Dump an entire HTTP request in Flask

Tags: http, flask, werkzeug

I am using Flask to create some json API's and use them with software that doesn't know about HTTP (just plain old network sockets).  Is there a way I can dump the entire http request to the console? Headers, body and all?  I want to be able to use this dump to talk to it over something like a telnet connection, so I'm looking for whole request.  If Flask can't do this kind of logging, any other ideas?

Comment: Why are you using a webframework with software that can't speak HTTP?

Comment: To answer your question: Flask doesn't have access to the entire HTTP request, the lowest level it has access to is a WSGI environment.

Comment: I am using code on some embedded hardware to provide an alternative interface to the web version.  I can have is send strings over a socket, but I my low-level protocol knowledge is still a little lacking here

Comment: So this code on this low-level hardware should somehow make HTTP requests to your webapp?

Comment: The piece of hardware has basic networking, with sockets, but no http libraries to help out.  Since http is a text protocol, I should still be able to carefully craft some commands to hook up the buttons on the hardware

Comment: peterw: Which language are you able to use on that hardware? Implementing the subset of HTTP you need might work, but it's still a bad idea, so i'd consider that as a last resort option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way I've figure out to do this is use Wireshark, and its "Follow TCP Stream" feature.  This will give me a dump of an entire http transaction, at the protocol level.